# How to get Multiindex columns in panda dataframe from nested json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to load the information of a tweet I retrieved from Tweepy,and it is in the form of a nested json. If I use the `df = pd.json_normalize(d)`, I get a flattened version. If I use `df = pd.DataFrame(list(tweets.find()))`, the nested jsons remain as jsons in the column under which they were nested. **Is there a way to get all the nested jsons to be multiindex columns?**

For instance, if the json looks like

```
a={'one':
      {'one.one':1,'one.two':2},
  'two':2}
```

I would want to get a dataframe where I can access: `pd['one']['one.one']`

If I use `json_normalise`, I would only be getting 'one.one'as a seperate column, and would not get 'one'column at all.
On using `pd.DataFrame(list(tweets.find()))`, I would be getting the column 'one' but no column named 'one.one'
I am aiming to get a  dataframe like this:

```
         one                two
    one.one   one.two         
0         1          2        2
1 -1.392909        NaN  0.005477
```

Comment: Please include the desired dataframe you are trying to get?

Comment: I did now. A dataframe with multiindex columns

Comment: Where does the second row in the dataframe come from?

Comment: @Roy2012 This is just to show the structure of the dataframe I aim to get at, I did not write the code here to append the value. I have the first entry, and I want to add that second row when I manage to create the dataframe.